# New Jersey budget plan

Tags: united-states, budget

Governor Murphy of NJ has proposed a state budget plan.  I've been trying to find a copy of the budget plan on the internet, but can't find it.  I also checked on the NJ state website.

Is it available to the public?

Answer (score 4):

Took a good amount of digging:

http://www.nj.gov/treasury/omb/publications/19bib/BIB.pdf

Comment: Links only answers are frowned on. An outline or description is normally asked for.

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained how to locate New Jersey's budget documents generally. That way, someone with the same problem in the future could learn how to find the one they want (rather than only this one).